# Convert int to string and return

Tags: java, string, int

I want the code to get an int as an argument and add 3 if the age is odd and adds 2 if even and then return as string.

With this code i get

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Hasn't it been converted at line 9?

```
public String whatAge() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int age = input.nextInt();

    if (age % 2 == 0) {
        age += 2;
    }
    else 
        age += 3;

    Integer.toString(age);

    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code says this:

```
    Integer.toString(age);  // line #9
    return age;
```

That should be:

```
    return Integer.toString(age);
```

---

> Hasn't it been converted at line 9?

Well yes ... but then you threw away the `String` result of the `toString` call and returned the original `int` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign returning `String` to variable or you can just return it. `toString()` `return` the `String` value of `Integer` you need to take it. Here you didn't take that returning `String`.

```
 String str=Integer.toString(age); // str is the returning String
 return str;
```

Or

```
return Integer.toString(age); // returning result of toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way **return Integer.toString(age);**

```
public class intToS {

    public String whatAge() {

        int age = 25;

        if (age % 2 == 0) {
            age += 2;
        } else
            age += 3;

        return Integer.toString(age);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        intToS obj = new intToS();
        System.out.println("Age = "+obj.whatAge());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You arent saving the converted value to any `string` before returning it, you return age which remains an `int`:

```
String result=Integer.toString(age);

return result;
```

Answer (score -2):

do it like this and it should work:

`return age.toString();`

Comment: `age` is primitive `int`. Don't have `toString()` there.